# Cmake errors when using LLVM 5.0.0 from brew

Tags: cmake, homebrew

I'm trying to use the stock LLVM 5.0.0 provided by Homebrew (MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3). LLVM is installed on my machine under `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.0/`

Now, in my project, I have the following lines in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Find the LLVM library
find_package( LLVM 5.0.0 REQUIRED )
include_directories( "${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS}" )
link_directories(${LLVM_LIBRARY_DIRS})
message(STATUS "LLVM include dirs: ${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

If I run CMake without any parameters, I get:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:74 (find_package):
>    By not providing "FindLLVM.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
>    asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "LLVM", but
>    CMake did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "LLVM" (requested
>    version 5.0.0) with any of the following names:
>
> ```
> LLVMConfig.cmake
> llvm-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "LLVM" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
>    "LLVM_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "LLVM"
>    provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
>    installed.

It tells me that it couldn't find LLVM. So, I pass the path to the LLVM_DIR, like this:

```
cmake .. -DLLVM_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.0/share/cmake/modules/
```

I would expect everything to work. Instead I get the following error:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:74 (find_package):
>    Could not find a configuration file for package "LLVM" that is compatible
>    with requested version "5.0.0".
>
> The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:
>
> /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.0/share/cmake/modules/llvm-config.cmake,
>      version: unknown

For some reason the version is not present anywhere in the `share/cmake/modules` directory.

How can I fix this, without changing the brew-installed LLVM?

Comment: Try to get rid of LLVM's version number, e.g. `find_package(LLVM REQUIRED)`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. The brew install has an invalid version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer. I was passing a wrong path to LLVM_DIR.
I just have to use another directory (buried in `lib`, not in `share`):

```
cmake .. -DLLVM_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/5.0.0/lib/cmake/llvm/
```

Not sure why brew decided to install 2 versions of CMake helpers for LLVM, one in `share` and one in `lib`.